# Efficient 2 int coordinate object store and get performance. hashmap or array

Tags: java, arrays, performance, hashmap, hashcode

Im working on a picture : Width * Height

Im not working with All pixel, only some of them on witch i instanciate an object.

The super efficient structure to get object is a 2 dimensional array : Object[W][H]

But, for Huge picture, java allocate memory for each cell, and get an out of memory quickly.

The problem is How to get the fastest way an object with get(X,Y)

So i tried many solutions to store my X/Y object :

**Hasmap :**

```
new HashMap<Integer,Point>();
```

or

```
new HashMap<Integer,Point>(W*H);
```

I get a performance improvment with size specification (2)

**Hashcode for 2 int :**

```
 int sum = x + y;
 return sum * (sum + 1) / 2 + x;
```

or

```
return   x * 31 + y;
```

or

```
return Long.hashCode( (x << 32) | (y & 0XFFFFFFFFL));
```

or

```
int result = (int) x;
    result = 31 * result + (int) (x >>> 32);
    result = 31 * result + (int) y;
    return 31 * result + (int) (y >>> 32);
```

I get the best performance with solution 1 for hascode

My last solution (**and the most efficient**) is to try an array for the X and a hashmap for Y :

```
HashMap[] LESX=new HashMap[W];
for(int i=0;i<W;i++)
    {
        LESX[i]=new HashMap<Integer,Object>();
    }
```

then the put is :

```
LESX[x].put(y, new Object());
```

and get :

```
LESX[X].get(Y);
```

And an Exist test :

```
return LESX[X].containsKey(Y);
```

My question is : 
is there another solution to get faster ? 
knowing that :

- the Put() doesn't matter
- the Get(X,Y) is used millions during process , in multithread access context
- using Point, Location, Dimension etc. class of java for HashCode doesn't improve

Comment: You may try [`TLongObjectHashMap`](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/hash/TLongObjectHashMap.html) with `(long) x << 32 | (y & 0xffffffffL)` as the keys. But any discussion here about *faster* and *slower* is just a speculation unless there is an objective benchmark.

Comment: The objective benchmatk is the time processing. I do not publish them because its evidence for me. We are talking abour minutes , and may be hours on some work. When i begun "cleaning" my code i was about 18min on a work, now im at 8 minutes for the same work, just working with lambda+hascode improvment. Im gonna try your hascode solution and give you the result. But strangly, the solution 1 for hashcode, even with 3 addition and 3 multip is faster thant lang bit opperation... i'll post feedback soon